# How to push different microservices projects in a single git repository

Tags: java, spring, git, github, intellij-idea

so i have built a microservice project in intellij with springboot. I now want to store it in github as in one repository with folders representing different services. I made a parent project Optima Growth and imported other services as modules.
Now the error im facing is that all these services being different projects have their own .git folder and hence their own local repository.
I want to store the whole application in a single repository but cant as these services have their own repositories and the github repo only shows the project iv pushed last and not all in folders.
[image]

i thought of using submodules so i can version control all services and put all services in one github remote repo but it requires me to first make github remote repos of these services which can take time as i incresae the services. Also i thought of removing .git from all these services and just adding all code and files to a single repo but intellij wont let me do it as the modules work like different projects. Please tell me how to store it in a single repository.

Comment: Remove all `.git` folders, create new git repo for all, push.

Answer (score 1):

As M.Deinum mentioned in the comment, you should delete `.git` folders in all subdirectories.
If Intellij doesn't let you do this, do it by file manager.
I've done this in a sample project that you can see here:
[github/microservice](https://github.com/Mojtaba98mz/microservice)

The only difference is that I didn't import other services as modules.
Intellij recognizes them as a service like this image:
[services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueULF.png)